# Recursion function to find power of number

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm writing a recursion function to find the power of a number and it seems to be compiling but doesn't output anything.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int stepem(int n, int k);

int main()
{
    int x, y;

    cin >> x >> y;

    cout << stepem(x, y) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int stepem(int n, int k)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * stepem(n, k-1);
}
```

I tried debugging it, and it says the problem is on this line :
`return n * stepem(n, k-1);`

k seems to be getting some weird values, but I can't figure out why?

Comment: Well the truth is that your `n` is never changing. It probably is doing infinite recursion until your stacks get filled.

Comment: Isn't that a infinite loop?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Well, it shouldn't change, why should it? I want to multiply the number `n` for `k` times.

Comment: I think that you want to check `k` and not `n`, am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderScholz no because the recursion isn't tail recursive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be checking the exponent k, not the number itself which never changes.

```
int rPow(int n, int k) {
    if (k <= 0) return 1;
    return n * rPow(n, --k);
}
```

Your k is getting weird values because you will keep computing until you run out of memory basically, you will create many stack frames with k going to "-infinity" (hypothetically).

That said, it is theoretically possible for the compiler to give you a warning that it will never terminate - in this particular scenario. However, it is naturally impossible to solve this in general (look up the Halting problem).

Comment: If the function is tail recursive, it might be able to recurse idefinitely without using more memory than the function really need.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Correct, you could eliminate the call and reuse the stack frame, I just wanted to give him an idea of what's happening if there is no base case.

Comment: Yeah, I added my tail call optimizable version. While having `k` bigger than `MAX_INT` might not create a stackoverflow with my version, it should give unexpected results at some points if the numbers are too high for ints.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I am not sure about this and too lazy to look up but I think that C++ doesn't actually enforce this "optimization" (unlike Haskell and probably other functional languages) - So meh :). (Yes, there is even difference in semantic implications should such optimization be preset, but yes, meh.)

Comment: As far as I know, the language doesn't enforce it but most compiler might be already doing such kind of optimization for a long time. I'm pretty sure GCC does it by default.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is wrong:

```
int stepem(int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0) // should be k, not n!
        return 1;
    else if (k == 1) // this condition is wrong
        return 1;
    else
        return n * stepem(n, k-1);
}
```

If you call it with `stepem(2, 3)` (for example), you'll get 2 * 2 * 1 instead of 2 * 2 * 2 * 1.  You don't need the else-if condition:

```
int stepem(int n, unsigned int k) // unless you want to deal with floating point numbers, make your power unsigned
{
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    return n * stepem(n, k-1);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `return n;` when `k == 1` in your revision of the original code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, because the return statement will handle it:  `n * stepem(n, 0)` will equate to `n * 1`.  The only exit condition you need is for `k == 0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, if you mean the first code block, I just corrected the conditional checks to show how the algorithm is wrong.  The corrected code is in the second block (which does not have the `k == 1` check at all).

Comment: The first block was what I was referring to. It is a legitimate algorithm and works correctly if the second `return` is changed to `return n;` — even though it would also work correctly (but slightly more expensively) if the `else if (k == 1) return n;` condition were removed, as in your second version of the code.  The difference is one less function call vs one more test — not huge.

Comment: I didn't fix that part in the first code block because I wanted to show that returning 1 from that block was mathematically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test it but I guess it should give you what you want and it is tail recursive.

```
int stepemi(int result, int i int k) {
    if (k == 0 && result == i)
        return 1;
    else if (k == 0)
        return result;
    else
        return stepem(result * i, i, k-1);
}

int stepem(int n, int k) {
   return stepemi(n, n, k);
}
```

The big difference between this piece of code and the other example is that my version could get optimized for tail recursive calls. It means that when you call `stepemi` recursively, it doesn't have to keep anything in memory. As you can see, it could replace the variable in the current stack frame without having to create a new one. No variable as to remain in memory to compute the next recursion.

If you can have optimized tail recursive calls, it also means that the function will used a fixed amount of memory. It will never need more than 3 ints.

On the other hand, the code you wrote at first creates a tree of stackframe waiting to return. Each recursion will add up to the next one.

Comment: may you mean 3 `int` instead of 3 `byte`?

Comment: Using two functions seems a little unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @jcm yeah we're not using 8bit chips anymore... :(

Comment: @JonathanLeffler then only use the first one with 3 parameters. The second function is just a shorthand and isn't necessary. That's the price you have to pay to have tail recursive functions.

Comment: I give you one up vote because we proposed the solution in comments before it was available as an actual response :-(

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to post an answer according to my comment (seems I missed adding a comment and not a response :-D). I think, mainly, you have two errors: you're checking `n` instead of `k` and you're returning `1` when power is 1, instead of returning `n`. I think that `stepem` function should look like:

Edit: Updated to support negative exponents by @ZacHowland suggestion

```
float stepem(int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (k<0) ?((float) 1/n) * stepem(n, k+1)  :n * stepem(n, k-1);
}
```

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix ;-)

Comment: The only issue I have with this is the `<=0` check.  If `k` is negative, the return value (mathematically) would be a fraction, not 1.  The safer solution is to prevent negative numbers for the exponent, altogether (unless the desire is to actually handle floating point numbers).

Comment: @ZacHowland I agree that, being strict, using negative exponential, would mean return a fraction but, taking into account proposed function signature, I assumed that only positive values are expected. I would update it to support negative exponents ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Power.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


#include <stream>

using namespace std;

int power(int n, int k);

void main()
{
    int x,y;

    cin >>x>>y;

    cout<<power(x,y)<<endl;


}

int power(int n, int k)
{
    if (k==0)
        return 1;
    else if(k==1) // This condition is working :) //
        return n;
    else
        return n*power(n,k-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your Program  is wrong and it Does not support negative value given by user,
check this one

```
int power(int n, int k){
'if(k==0)
 return 1;
 else if(k<0)
 return ((x*power(x,y+1))*(-1));
 else
 return n*power(n,k-1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i changed your variable names
but i hope you will understand;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double  power(double , int);// it should be double because you also need to handle negative powers which may cause fractions

int main()
{
 cout<<"please enter the number to be powered up\n";
 double number;
 cin>>number;
 cout<<"please enter the number to be powered up\n";
 int pow;
 cin>>pow;
 double result = power(number, pow);
 cout<<"answer is "<<result <<endl;
}

 double power( double x, int n)
{

if (n==0)
    return 1;
if (n>=1)
    /*this will work OK even when n==1 no need to put additional condition as n==1
    according to calculation it will show x as previous condition will force it to be x;
    try to make pseudo code on your note book you will understand what i really mean*/
    if (n<0)
    return x*power(x, n-1);
   return 1/x*power(x, n+1);// this will handle negative power as you should know how negative powers are handled in maths
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int stepem(int n, int k)

{
    if (k == 0)   //not n cause you have to vary y i.e k if you want to find x^y
        return 1; 
    else if (k == 1)
        return n;  //x^1=x,so when k=1 it should be x i.e n
    else
        return n * stepem(n, k-1);
}
```